# Trouble choosing and uploading a pdf file using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to create a script in python using post http request to upload this ***[pdf](https://filebin.net/bue7c3iz4d04c492)*** file in a webpage. I've tried like the following but unfortunately, the script could not upload the file.

This is the [log-in](https://jobs.commerzbank.com/index.php?ac=login) link. Here are the username ***`SmthShift_123`*** and password ***`7/B!yzRd8wuK!N2`*** for your consideration. Now go to [this page](https://jobs.commerzbank.com/index.php?ac=application&jobad_id=30670) and click on the last tab `Anhang` where you will find the upload option.

To let you visualize - ***[this](https://filebin.net/1t26mmi4pip3vtok)*** is how that page looks like.

This is my try so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

login_url = 'https://jobs.commerzbank.com/index.php?ac=login'
application_link = 'https://jobs.commerzbank.com/index.php?ac=application&jobad_id=30670'
target_link = 'https://jobs.commerzbank.com/index.php?ac=application&page=6'
upload_link = 'https://jobs.commerzbank.com/inc/candidate_attachments.php'


with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(login_url)
    sauce = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    elem = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in sauce.select('input[name]')}
    elem['username'] = 'SmthShift_123'
    elem['password'] = '7/B!yzRd8wuK!N2'

    s.post(login_url,data=elem)
    s.get(application_link)
    resp = s.get(target_link)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"lxml")
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['form-control'] = 'Anschreiben'
    payload['upload'] = 'Datei hochladen'
    payload['save'] = ''

    files = {
        'searchButton': open('CV.pdf','rb')
    }
    s.post(upload_link,files=files,data=payload)
```

When I execute the above script, it neither saves that file nor throws any error.

I also tried like this (using selenium only to do the uploading) but the script can't choose and upload the file either:

```
s.post(login_url,data=elem)
s.get(application_link)
resp = s.get(target_link)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(resp.url)
driver.delete_all_cookies()

for cookie in s.cookies.items():
    driver.add_cookie({"name": cookie[0], "value": cookie[1]})

driver.get(resp.url)

select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#upload_category"))))
select.select_by_visible_text("Lebenslauf")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#upload_file"))).send_keys("C://Users/WCS/Desktop/CV.pdf")
```

> How can I choose and upload the pdf file using requests?

Comment: When I visit the upload page, being logged in with the credentials you provided, I get a general error message. I don't know if anyone else has this problem, but I can't test the request parameters, unless I have a valid request to compare them to.

Comment: I think it works if you break the final request in two parts. The first request uploads the file and is submitted to "/inc/candidate_attachments.php" with parameters "{'category':the category, 'action':'upload', 'application_token':the token}" and files "{'attachment':the file}". The 'category' value is one of the options of the 'Dateityp' select tag.

Comment: The second request is submitted to "/index.php" with parameters "{'ac':'application','language':'de','current':'application','save':'','formpage':6, 'application_token':the token}"

Comment: I tried to comply with your suggestion but perhaps I missed something along the lines and that is the reason it did not work out @t.m.adam. Ain't ***[this](https://filebin.net/l9bmxrulpcl00w8z)*** how you meant? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The first request works if you use those parameters `{'category':the category, 'action':'upload', 'application_token':the token}`. The token can be aquired from the `soup` object and the `category` is one from the 'Dateityp' tag (for example,  'Sonstiges' is 12). We can verify this because the file is added to the list of documents. For the second request I'm not so sure though.

Comment: It appears to be working @t.m.adam. What I can't understand is where did you find this payload `{'category':the category, 'action':'upload', 'application_token':the token}`. I looked for this payload in dev tools but no luck. Thanks.

Comment: You can see the request in dev tools if you select the file and file category and press the upload button - not the save form button.

Comment: I did but what I saw in there is everything except for the payload option. Do you use chrome dev tools? I will be happy to accept your answer if you post one. Things become difficult when you are not around @t.m.adam. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could upload it using selenium. This website is tricky. It has a hidden `input` that only appears upon hovering a button to upload.

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


login_url = 'https://jobs.commerzbank.com/index.php?ac=login'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(login_url)
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'nav_login').click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.popover-content #quick-login-username').send_keys('SmthShift_123')
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.popover-content #quick-login-password').send_keys('7/B!yzRd8wuK!N2')
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.popover-content #quick_login_form button[type='submit']").click()

driver.get('https://jobs.commerzbank.com/index.php?ac=application&jobad_id=30670')
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".applicationform-tab[data-pagenumber='6']").click()

select = Select(
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#upload_category"))))
select.select_by_visible_text("Lebenslauf")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#upload_file")))

e = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#upload_file")
# Hover over and wait for tooltip to appear
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(e, 5, 5)
action.perform()
sleep(3)

# Now, let's search for a hidden input and send keys
e = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='attachment']")
e.send_keys("/<path>/CV.pdf")

# And click to upload:
e = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#start_file_upload_button")
e.click()
```

Hope, this will work for you as well. Good luck!

Comment: this is interesting, ok, will do tonight

Answer (score 1):

**Solution1**

[`js file`](https://jobs.commerzbank.com/cust/coba/js/frontend.min.js) has `attachFfwAjaxUpload()` function, to upload attachment file.

[`find(name, attrs, recursive, text, **kwargs)`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#find(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20**kwargs)) - match and return first object.

**Ex.**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

login_url = 'https://jobs.commerzbank.com/index.php?ac=login'
application_link = 'https://jobs.commerzbank.com/index.php?ac=application&jobad_id=30670'
target_link = 'https://jobs.commerzbank.com/index.php?ac=application&page=6'
upload_link = 'https://jobs.commerzbank.com/inc/candidate_attachments.php'

with requests.Session() as sessionObj:
    sessionObj.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'
    res = sessionObj.get(login_url)
    sauce = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    elem = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in sauce.select('input[name]')}
    elem['username'] = 'SmthShift_123'
    elem['password'] = '7/B!yzRd8wuK!N2'

    sessionObj.post(login_url,data=elem)
    sessionObj.get(application_link)
    resp = sessionObj.get(target_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"lxml")

    # get attachment form tag object
    form = soup.find("form", attrs={'action':'index.php'})
    payload = dict()

    # set upload category
    # you have four category option, values are 2, 1, 4 and 12, 
    # select one value option
    payload['category'] = '12'
    payload['application_token'] = form.find('input', 
                        attrs={'name':'application_token'}).get('value','')
    payload['action'] = 'upload'

    # you can see upload file attachment attachFfwAjaxUpload() function in 
    # frontend.min.js file in browser source tab between 38878 to 38903 lines
    print(payload)

    with open('CV.pdf', 'rb') as f:

        file = {"attachment": f}
        atteachment_response = sessionObj.post(upload_link, files=file, data=payload)

        # print post request response status code 
        print(atteachment_response.status_code)
        print(atteachment_response.text)
```

**Solution2 - By selenium to upload file**

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By    
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

login_url = 'https://jobs.commerzbank.com/index.php?ac=login'
application_link = 'https://jobs.commerzbank.com/index.php?ac=application&jobad_id=30670'

driver = Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(login_url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'login')))

# set username
username = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'login-username')
username.send_keys('SmthShift_123')

# set password
password = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'login-password')
password.send_keys('7/B!yzRd8wuK!N2')

# login
login = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='login']//button[@type='submit']")
login.click()

# after login switched into target url
driver.get(application_link)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".applicationform-tab[data-pagenumber='6']").click()

# wait and select upload category
select = Select(
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "upload_category"))))
select.select_by_value("12")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "upload_file")))

e = driver.find_element(By.ID, "upload_file")

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(e, 5, 5)
action.perform()

# find attachment input tag by name
upload = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "attachment")

# set pdf file path
upload.send_keys("/CV.pdf")

# upload file
upload = driver.find_element(By.ID, "start_file_upload_button")
upload.click()
```

Comment: Yep, I got it. The thing is the payload usually is found in relevant requests in network tab as well.